# Adding items to a `useState` variable `array` while mapping it causes too many re-renders error in React native function component

Tags: arrays, react-native, react-hooks, use-state

I am rendering content depending on a variable like this:

```
    <View style={styles.values}>{handleRender()}</View>
```

The `handleRender()` function:

```
  const handleRender = () => {
    return periodType === "Day"
      ? renderDaySelector()
      : periodType === "Week"
      ? renderWeekSelector()
      : periodType === "Month"
      ? renderMonthSelector()
      : renderYearSelector();
  };
```

My problem is with the `renderWeekSelector()`:

```
  const renderWeekSelector = () => {
    let date = new Date();
    loadWeeks(date);
    return (
      <ScrollView
        style={{ width: "100%" }}
        onMomentumScrollEnd={() => laodWeeks(date)}
      >
        {weeks.map((e) => {
          return <AppCheckBox key={e.id} value={e.text} />;
        })}
      </ScrollView>
    );
  };
```

Which calls the `loadWeeks(date)` function :

```
 const loadWeeks = (date) => {
    let weeksWillUpdate = [...weeks];

    let weekString = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      ... preparing the weekString;
      weeksWillUpdate.push({
        id: weeks.length + i,
        date: date,
        text: weekString,
      });
      weekString = "";
    }
// the problem is here when setting the weeks array variable
    setWeeks(weeksWillUpdate);

  };
```

The weeks variable:

```
  const [weeks, setWeeks] = useState([]);
```

This code causes the `too many re-renders` error.
How can I fix it, please?
Thanks.

**Update**
I have also tried this approach:

```
setWeeks((oldWeeks) => [
        ...oldWeeks,
        {
          id: weeks.length + i,
          date: date,
          text: weekString,
        },
      ]);
```

and removed `setWeeks(weeksWillUpdate)` but still the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem solved**

Turned out that my problems lay in where I am calling the `loadWeeks()` method.
I have changed my code to load the weeks outside the `renderWeeksSelector()` method and the re-render error is gone.